# What Apple API's have C++ accessibility and not just Objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a way to know what Apple API's I can use with C++ and not just Objective-C. iOS 7.

Is there a resource or way I would know this when I am planning out my apps functionality?

I know I will need some Objective-C at least. I can handle that. I am just not as comfortable with Objective-C at this point in time but I still have app ideas.

Comment: no better way of learning than just diving in.

Comment: and I keep telling myself that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am just not as comfortable with Objective-C at this point in time but I still have app ideas.

Objective-C is a very simple language. You could specify all of the things it adds to plain C on a couple of pages. The syntax looks odd at first, but that disappears quickly. The hard stuff is all down to it being a superset of C, which won't be a problem for you if you're used to C++.

The iOS APIs, on the other hand, are not simple at all. There are loads of them and they take time to learn.

Learning the language is easy compared to learning the APIs. Learning the APIs is easier if you use them in the native language. So my advice would be to do that. Or, possibly use a C++ framework that wraps them up in C++ classes. Using the native APIs in C++ (to the extent that it's possible) isn't a good idea.

Comment: are you saying that Apple provides the best functionality through obJ-C and those API's? Curious since you said: "Using the native APIs in C++ isn't a good idea though."

Comment: yes. I'm not him but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C and C++ do OOP very, very differently.  Objective-C does things closer to real message sending, as opposed to directly calling a function.  That allows for a level of dynamism that makes C++'s head spin, and means that C++ objects and Objective-C objects are incompatible in a bunch of ways.

If you're intent on trying to use C++ to manipulate Cocoa objects, Objective-C++ was (is?) an attempt to do with C++ what Objective-C does with C.  I haven't heard much good about it, though.

Other than that, you will need to become familiar with `objc_msgSend` (the function Objective-C uses to actually send a message to an object).  Cause you'll be using it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well trying to keep the answer simple. There is no conflict between C++ and Objective-C.
You can use both for your development purpose and even in a same project/class.

Unfortunately, Apple does not expose any direct application level API in C++, rather it sticks to Objective-C for that purpose. However, Apple's foundation APIs are still based on pure C and thus you can create your own wrapper in C++, to call those foundation frameworks to build your own application framework. But that would certainly incur a huge overhead on the development process.

I recommend you to stick to Objective-C based AppKit/UIKit for UI and front-end development whereas you can still use pure C/C++ for your business objects. For example, if you are developing a game, you can create C/C++ classes for implementing your processing/rendering logic and implement only the screen output logic in Objective-C. You can safely use C/C++ classes/methods inside your Objective-C class. So you dont have to worry about the interoperability.